# Network request failed while calling a api running on local server

Tags: reactjs, react-native

```
fetch('https://mylocalip:5000/api/token')
.then(function (response) {
  console.log('response : ',response)
        return response.json();
    }).then (function (response) {
        this.setState({
    token: response.token
  });
    }).catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

I read in issues on react native and use my ip to call local api. but still get network error. Im on latest version of react-native 0.55.4.

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct uri should be http://mylocalip:5000/api/token (remove https) or https://mylocalip/api/token (remove port)

Comment: the api is running locally on port 5000 so i need to have PORT number there

Comment: @Avinash so you need to use http instead of https due to https is port 443

Answer (score 0):

So I finally figured out that the issue was with the certificate. React native was not able to verify certificate self signed on localhost.